# Should a company be referred to as “he/she” or as “it”?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, pronouns, agreement, pronominal-agreement

When a customer represents a company, not a person, and a pronoun is needed to refer back to that customer, should one use *he/she*, or should one use *it*?

Comment: Apart from the well-known case of _she_ for vehicles and countries, _he_ and _she_ are hardly ever used for inanimates. If you referred to a corporate customer as _he_, most people would suppose you must be referring to an individual who contacted you from the company.

Comment: What does "represents" mean in this question?

Comment: @GEdgar: I meant, using the word "customer", but the customer is a company, not a person.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*It* or *they.*

> Google buys more of our servers than any other company. *They* have bought 4,000 servers from us.

Comment: Me, I would have said *they* there, not *it*.

Comment: Although, now, apparently, corporations are people...  So, hey, why not call it he?  You think Google is a him or a her? =o)

Comment: But if you use *they*, then shouldn't you begin with "Google buy more..."?  I guess that's the British way.

Answer (score 6):

Well, you definitely don’t want to use *he*, since there is no single male antecedent, nor *she* for similar reasons.

The notation *he/she* is severely unappealing for a whole multitude of reasons, but beyond its ugliness, it still won’t work here because there is no single notional individual behind it all.

That leaves you with *they* or *it*, either of which is fine. I don’t think a native speaker would bat an eye at either of those two. The difference is subtle, and not worth making a big deal over.

I ***believe*** I would be more likely to use *they* than I would to use *it* in this circumstance, but I’m not positive. You’d have to catch me doing it when I weren’t thinking about the whole idea, then see what I actually did.  Saying it over and over again in my mind has robbed it of any natural spontaneity, and I’m no longer sure what I’d do in practice.

Comment: In most contexts, British English would use _they_. But doesn't American English have a problem with treating ostensibly singular nouns as if they were plural?

Comment: @BarrieEngland Sometimes, perhaps, but to me *they* sounds much better here than *it*. American English does indeed use singular **verbs** for companies and sports teams, so “Apple has debuted” not *have*, or “Chicago has decided” not *have*. But for me at least, only the verb is singular, and then only with the noun itself — not with the pronoun. Therefore in my own speech, the pronoun that goes with those tends to be plural. I think of a company as a “they” more than I think of it as an *it* — but it depends, as this sentence demos. Depends whether I’m thinking of the firm as people, maybe.

Comment: So would this be a normal sentence in AmEng? ‘The company has made a substantial loss and they must review their options carefully.’

Comment: @BarrieEngland Well, it would certainly be a normal sentence for ***me***, but I am contaminated. :)

Comment: @Barrie: I think I would use "it" in your example: "The company has made a substantial loss, and it must review its options carefully", but "they" in the example: "Google buys more of our servers than any other company. They have bought ...".  But neither pronoun would be wrong in AmE for either example. What is wrong is saying "Google have ...".

Answer (score 0):

'It/they' are totally okay. However, 'she' is also recommended considering organization/agencies, just as human beings, countries and vehicles, are also productive, hold lives of employees and give forth career growth opportunities etc. Use it! 'He' is not appropriate though - even countries are hardly ever referred to as 'he' unless in French vocabulary