# Refer to an entity with "it" or "she" or "he"

Tags: word-choice

Related to this [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/96903/121336), but it's a slightly different question though.

Consider this sentence. I prefer to use the singular form.

> The advantage for the bank is that he/she/it can employ the capital (the loan) during a certain time.

Which is the correct usage? He, she or it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use *it* because *bank* is gender neutral. *It* is used with nouns that have no gender, such as *bank*, *dress*, and *tree*.

*He* is used with male people (and often animals): *John*, *Dad*, *Spot.*

*She* is used with female people (and often animals): *Rebecca*, *Aunt Meredith*, *Mrs. Fluffywhiskers.* *She* is also sometimes used to refer to ships and countries, but this is often considered archaic.

Answer (score 3):

Non-living entities are generally an 'it.'  Except for moving vehicles of varying types, such as ships, which are generally referred to as 'she'.  Except enemy vehicles, which are 'he' or 'it.'

Comment: Interesting, why enemy vehicles are considered male?